# Django - Sitemap - Manually set absolute urls

Tags: python, django, sitemap, django-sitemaps

I'm generating a sitemap but the website that this sitemap is for has a different URL routing and a different domain.

I thought that overriding `location` method will work but the problem is that Django automatically adds `Site` url before each url.

```
http://example.comhttps://thewebsite.com...


<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url><loc>http://example.comhttps://thewebsite.com/article/123/slug</loc><lastmod>2021-05-10</lastmod>
         <changefreq>hourly</changefreq><priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

```
class WebsiteSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "hourly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self) -> typing.List:
        items = []
        items.extend(Article.objects.home())
        return items

    def location(self, obj: typing.Union[Article]):
        return obj.website_full_url

    def lastmod(self, obj: typing.Union[Article]) -> datetime:
        return obj.modified
```

Is there a way to tell Django not to build the URL automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by building a custom template tag. I use that [tag](https://www.fraydit.com/blogs/wagtail-sitemap-in-docker/) to replace the `URL` in the Sitemap template.